# How can i get each line of this string with VB6

Tags: string, vb6

I want to know how I can get each line of this string until the next `@`.

```
 @cnb Santander 
 @cnn VENTA 
 @br 
 @cnn PRUEBAS INTEGRACIONES DLL
```

so I can have it on different line like:

```
 @cnb Santander
 @cnn VENTA
```

I have tried using `Split` function like this:

```
Dim sLines() As String, L As Long
sLines = Split(Text1.Text, vbCrLf)
```

but it seems that `vbCrLf` is not working

also tried:

```
sLines = Split(Text1.Text, " ")
```

Comment: [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) on `@`, [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) on `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Split on the `@` then when you set the values loop the array and append the `@` back

Comment: `sLines= Mid$(Replace$(Tex1.Text, "@", vbCrLf + "@"), 3)` quick and dirty way, as you need to check Text1.text for emptiness, <3 length etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text was manually entered into a multiline TextBox, then each press of Return will add a CrLf combination and your code should work just fine.

Since the code doesn't work, I assume that the text is being loaded from somewhere else, and that the likely problem is that the text is Unix formatted, meaning that it only contains Lf characters, not CrLf. (I've also come across Cr on it's own before too.)

If this is the case, then you simply need to convert the line feeds first. I usually convert everything to single Lf characters when splitting like this...

```
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sTemp As String
sTemp = Replace$(Text1.Text, vbCrLf, vbLf)  ' Convert CrLf combinations to Lf only
sTemp = Replace$(sTemp, vbCr, vbLf)         ' Convert any remaining Cr's to Lf's
sLines = Split(sTemp, vbLf)                 ' Spilt on Lf instead of CrLf
```